# Mysql: Order Results by number of matching rows in Second Table

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure the best way to word this question so bear with me.

Table A has following columns:

- id
- name
- description

Table B has the following columns:

- id
- a_id(foreign key to Table A)
- ip_address
- date

Basically Table B contains a row for each time a user views a row from Table A.

My question is how do I sort Table A results, based on the number of matching rows in Table B.

i.e

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TableA 
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM TableB 
           where TableB.a_id = TableA.id)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem with the query you already have?

Comment: Wow. I wrote that query as Pseudo-code without actually thinking to test it out. Never thought it would actually work but I just tested it and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT a.*
         , b.cnt
      FROM TableA a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT a_id
                         , COUNT(*) cnt
                      FROM TableB b
                   GROUP BY a_id) b
   ON a.id = b.a_id
     ORDER BY b.cnt
```

Comment: Note: This omits rows from the result if they have no rows in TableB.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everyone. Thanks dcp, this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick.

```
select a.id, a.name, a.description, count(b.id) as count 
   from TableA as a 
   inner join TableB as b on a.id = b.a_id 
   group by a.id, a.name, a.description order by count
```

Comment: Note: This omits rows from the result if they have no rows in TableB.

Answer (score 0):

Your query already does what you want. You might want to add DESC if you want the rows with the largest number of rows first:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableB where TableB.a_id = TableA.id) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.description, count(b.id) FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableB b on b.a_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.description ORDER BY COUNT(b.id);
```

You can add an DESC to the ORDER BY, maybe that is what you need:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.description, count(b.id) FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableB b on b.a_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.description ORDER BY COUNT(b.id) DESC;
```